# Why can't I access the next element in a string when I increment the pointer by one?

Tags: c, string, pointers, dereference

I'm trying to increment a pointer to a string by hand using the dereference operator like I've seen it work in the while loop I have bellow. It works for the first character, but when I try to increment the pointer by hand like it is in the while loop, it doesn't work and I get back garbage. Could someone please tell me what I'm not understanding? This code works the way I expect it.

```
char *pointToString = "some string or something"; 
printf("%c\n", *pointToString); // this returns the letter 's'
while(*pointToString != '\0'){
    printf("%c", *pointToString);
    *pointToString++;
}
```

This works and prints out 's' and then the string "some string or something", but why can't I access the second element of the string if I increment it by hand? When I do this, I get back garbage.

```
printf("%c\n", *pointToString+1);
```

This returns something other than the letter 'o'. I also tried this, but still got garbage:

```
printf("%c\n", *pointToString+sizeof(char));
```

I'm not sure if that's correct but I figured that I'm incrementing a pointer like I did in the while loop:

```
*pointToString++;
```

So why couldn't I do that by itself?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't deference pointer here: `   *pointToString++;`c remove the `*`.

Comment: What Jack said, because the dereferencing operation produces a value which you don't use (so the dereference or `*` may as well not be there).  The compiler will not do the fetch anyway, but it will warn you and you should be aiming for warning-free compilations (even with the compiler warning options set to be very fussy).

Comment: That code just works like you planned, it prints s in one line and then the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the next element using the expression

```
printf("%c\n", *pointToString+1);
```

because the unary operator `*` has higher precedence than binary `+`. First, the current character is accessed; then, `1` is added to it. Proper use of parentheses will fix this problem:

```
printf("%c\n", *(pointToString+1));
```

Reference: [Operator precedence table in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Besides that, `*pointToString++;` looks weird. Maybe it works by mistake: the (wrong) intention was `(*pointToString)++`, but instead it is *(pointToString++) with useless dereferencing.

Comment: Right, all you need to do is `pointToString++` which increments the pointer to the string, which is what it looks like you want.

Comment: `(*pointToString)++` causes undefined behaviour, you cannot modify a string literal

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, this should be your fix:

```
*(pointToString++); // Iterates first, and then has the pointer point to the correct value
```

This is what's happening in your one line:

```
*pointToString++; // Points to the value first and then iterates.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `*x++` means `*(x++)`